# Anaconda navigator doesn't run after standard installing on Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

After usual installation of Anaconda (I use standard instructions from the official documentation) I can't run anaconda navigator command. Terminal outputs the following error:

```
anaconda navigator
usage: anaconda [-h] [--disable-ssl-warnings] [--show-traceback] [-v] [-q]
                [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
                ...
anaconda: error: argument : invalid choice: 'navigator' (choose from 'auth', 'label', 'channel', 'config', 'copy', 'download', 'groups', 'login', 'logout', 'move', 'notebook', 'package', 'remove', 'search', 'show', 'upload', 'whoami')
```

How to fix it?  `conda update anaconda-navigator` doesn't work.
OS is Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

Comment: What if you try `anaconda-navigator`? (Note the dash in the middle, not space)

Comment: it's work, but terminal sents this: 2019-01-21 09:41:36,553 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064

Comment: That looks like an internal error related to whether or not VSCode is installed. As long as everything else works, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `anaconda navigator` use `anaconda-navigator` and in a few seconds it will launch.

Comment: From Review: The OP clearly stated that he already tried this. Therefore this post does not provide an answer to the question, and doesn't even serve as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give space and use anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

1.-Close your terminal

2.-Open new one,
and put

```
anaconda-navigator
```